# Uploading more than one file using AJAX and formData (individually, not multiple files together)

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, multipartform-data, form-data

I have a form in which three file uploads need to occur via three separate file inputs. Using AJAX and `formData` I can get the first file to upload, but any subsequent files are not uploaded.

I presume the issue is to do with this line of code:

`var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);`

and I guess I need to iterate in some way to determine the number of files for upload, however I'm not certain of the logic to make that happen. My code so far is as follows:

```
$("#uploadA, #uploadB, #uploadC").click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);
    var progress = $(this).prop("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        xhr: function() {  
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",function(e) {
                    if(e.lengthComputable){
                        $("#"+progress).attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
                    }
                }, false); 
            }
            return myXhr;
        },

        success: success,
        error: error,
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

});
```

For completion, sample HTML is as follows (with all three upload 'widgets' following same pattern):

```
<div class="form-box">
    <label for="A">Episode (MP3)</label>
    <progress max="100" value="0" id="progressA"></progress>
    <input type="file" name="a" value="a" id="a">
    <input type="button" value="Upload" id="uploadA" name="uploadA">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var formData = new FormData($(this).closest("form")[0]);
```

This will get the formData for the form containing the upload button that you clicked on, rather than the first form in the document. This assumes you have a separate form for each file.

If they're all in the same form, but you don't want to submit the entire form, you have to build the `formData` object by hand, as described in [Creating a FormData object from scratch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Creating_a_FormData_object_from_scratch)

```
var formData = new FormData();
var fileElement = $(this).prev()[0];
formData.append(fileElement.name, fileElement);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. It doesn't matter which upload I click on, the first one is the only one that gets loaded. But it could be any of the three that I choose first. That one works, the other two fail.

Comment: Are they in different forms? That's what my answer assumes.

Comment: No, sorry, they're all part of the same form. I should have specified that - apologies.